# Rails ajax error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my view file I have the following jQuery AJAX call

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
.
.
.
function updateFunction() {
    var input = JSON.stringify({data: hot.getData()});

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/cars/create",
        data: input,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: create_data_succ,
        error: create_data_error
    });
}

function create_data_error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

In may `cars_controller.rb` I have

```
  def create
    Car.create(name: params[:data][:name])
    flash.now[:notice] = 'New Car!'
    render "new"
  end
```

Data is saving to db but I can't see the notice message on the screen, instead I am getting the alert message (error callback jQuery AJAX)

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

what am I doing wrong? Any help much appreciated

Comment: Are you again converting response to JSON in `create_data_succ()`?

Comment: No I am not, `create_data_succ()` never executed

Comment: The data you're returning is not valid JSON. Check the responseText of the request in the network tab of the console to see exactly what is coming back

Comment: Change this `var input = JSON.stringify({data: hot.getData()});` to => `var input = JSON.parse({data: hot.getData()});`

Answer (score 2):

The data is sent correctly to the controller, since the data saves to the DB; the error lies with the response. You're doing a `render 'new'` on a successful create, which sends HTML back as response to the AJAX call. Maybe something like:

```
car = Car.new(name: params[:data][:name])
unless car.save
   render json: { errors: error }
end
...
```

If you need both html and json response (for whatever reason) you can do this via `respond_to`

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html  { render :new } 
   format.json  { render json: { ... } }
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help, after using `respond_to do |format|
   format.html  { render :new , notice: 'Created'} 
   format.json  { render json: { ... } }
end` , ther error alert is not displaying anymore. but still my flash notice is not showing up.. any idea ?

Comment: Since you're using an AJAX call, I don't think you can use flash notice unless the page redirects. You could just return the notice and display it via javascript instead.